# Task role defined by Terraform not working correctly for ECS scheduled task

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

Our team has a bunch of cron jobs running as an ECS scheduled task. Lately I'm adding a new job that requires the use of dynamodb, so I added the permissions in our terraform files, but keep on getting permission failure:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException:
User: arn:aws:sts::87********23:assumed-role/tcoe-tableau/74a408106bf543ee95dbe4841d00b0f7 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:87********23:table/tcoe-candyjar-metrics (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2;
Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: H52U8GCS1JAB74OJ6VSSEFLCQNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
```

My related terraform are as follows:

First, here are the ecs cluster and task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs-cluster" {
  name = "${var.stack_id}"
  tags {
    StackId = "${var.stack_id}"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "tags"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task-definition" {
  family                   = "${var.stack_id}"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = [
    "FARGATE"
  ]
  cpu                      = "${var.cpu}"
  memory                   = "${var.task_memory}"
  task_role_arn            = "${aws_iam_role.task_role.arn}"
  execution_role_arn       = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn}"
  container_definitions    = <<EOF
[
  {
    "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "${var.log_group}",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "${var.stack_id}"
        }
    },
    "ulimits": [
      {
        "name": "nofile",
        "softLimit": 4096,
        "hardLimit": 8192
      }
    ],
    "image": "${var.ecr_account}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${var.ecr_namespace}/${var.stack_id}:latest",
    "environment": [
      {"name": "ENV", "value": "${var.environment}" }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "privileged": false,
    "name": "${var.stack_id}",
    "memory": ${var.memory}
  }
]
EOF

  tags {
    StackId = "${var.stack_id}"
  }
}
```

Then here's the task role for the task definition:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "task_role" {
  name = "${var.stack_id}"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        ${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id == var.dev_account ? "\"AWS\": [\"arn:aws:iam::61********19:role/${var.dev_role_name}\"]," : ""}
        "Service": ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "task_role_profile" {
  name = "${var.stack_id}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.task_role.name}"
}
```

Finally here I'm adding the dynamodb-related policy to the task role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "main" {
  name = "${var.stack_id}-extra-policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.task_role.id}"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:Scan",
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:List*",
        "dynamodb:Get*",
        "dynamodb:Describe*",
        "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
        "dynamodb:Put*",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
        "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:87********23:table/tcoe-candyjar-metrics",
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:87********23:table/tcoe-candyjar-metrics/index/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here or missing anything?

Comment: What is `tcoe-tableau` role? Is it your ecs task role?

Comment: Yes, i think that's the task role. Now that you pointed that out, it just occurred to me that maybe instead of role = "${aws_iam_role.task_role.id", I should be using role = "${aws_iam_role.task_role.name", let me test that now. And I used task_role.id because I saw some example that uses id, I wonder when to use id vs name?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy the example in it does say it should be role = aws_iam_role.test_role.id, instead of role = aws_iam_role.test_role.name. my guess above is probably wrong

Comment: `aws_iam_role.task_role.id` is fine. The error says that `tcoe-tableau` has no  permissions. You have to confirm that this is your actual task role.

Comment: it should be, here:
resource "aws_iam_role" "task_role" {
  name = "${var.stack_id}"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
...
where ${var.stack_id} is tcoe-tableau.

Comment: Changing from aws_iam_role.test_role.id to aws_iam_role.test_role.name indeed made it work, i wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

I thought my failure was due to using role.id instead of role.name, and I wanted to figure out the differences between id and name, so I posted this question [aws iam role id vs role name in terraform, when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191146/aws-iam-role-id-vs-role-name-in-terraform-when-to-use-which), then the answer/comment indicated that that are exactly the same, which prompted me to go back and carefully check my commit history and build history, and I realized that the reason role.id didn't work was due to some human error I made. My new codes worked not because I used role.name, but because i unknowingly fixed the other error at the same time.

To summarize, role.id and role.name are exactly the same.

Comment: Wait so what's the solution then? I am having a this issue. Everything was working fine, I added a new environment variable took ages for it to be reflected. But now I am getting "is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem" Despite my task role clearly having that action. I didn't even change anything in that area.

Comment: The other annoying thing is that it seems to take a very long time for Cloudwatch to show me any logs. Is this the case for you too?

Comment: @Sigex It's been a while and I don't remember exactly what i did wrong, i can take a look tomorrow if you haven't figured out your issue yet. As for cloudwatch, sadly, we are the same, it does take some time, i think that's just how it is :(